# YDrive,XDrive,and ZDrive don't show a mode dropdown (Unity Editor)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to learn to build a game with unity and the video tutorial I am following shows him changing the YDrive mode to position and as I went to do that I noticed that My YDrive along with all of the other drives did not have a mode that I could change.  I was wondering if anyone else had this problem and how you resolved it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your question as it is, is unclear. We don't know what YDrive, XDrive, and ZDrive are or what tutorial you're following.

Comment: I am following the brakeys making an fps game with unity and it is episode 5 and the ydrive xdrive and zdrive are in the configurable joint component